# PHP MySQL: How to select multiple tables and return output summary with good performance?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, multiple-tables

**How to get result on PHP:**

- NU61 - sun - 2011
- KE2I - ball - 2000
- B8WO - point - 2008

---

**table_first** `SELECT id, order, date FROM table_first ORDER BY orders DESC`
return `id`, `date`

```
 id   | orders  | date
------+---------+------
 KE2I | 2       | 2000
 B8WO | 5       | 2008
 NU61 | 1       | 2011
```

**table_second** `SELECT key FROM table_second WHERE id=(id from table_first)` get `key` to reach `content` from `table_third`

```
 id   | key
------+-----------------
 KE2I | .b
 B8WO | .p
 NU61 | .s
```

**table_third** `SELECT content FROM table_third WHERE id=(key from table_second)` return `content`

```
 id   | content
------+-----------------
 .b   | ball
 .p   | point
 .s   | sun
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `table_first`.`id`,
       `table_third`.`content`,
       `table_first`.`date`
FROM `table_first`
LEFT JOIN `table_second` USING(`id`)
LEFT JOIN `table_third` ON `table_third`.`id`=`table_second`.`key`
```

Performance will not be a concern as long as you have indices on:

```
`table_first`.`id`
`table_second`.`id`
`table_second`.`key`
`table_third`.`id`
```

Comment: Any better solution for better performance on selecting data from 3 tables?

Comment: @Binyamin Isn't that your original question? This is my answer =)

Comment: Thanks! It seems working fine, except you forgot about `ORDER BY order DESC` and PHP, but nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

This query would do the trick:

```
SELECT t1.id, t3.content, t1.`date`
FROM table_first t1 
  JOIN table_second t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
  JOIN table_third t3 ON t2.`key` = t3.id;
```

Comment: Your SQL returns empty result: `MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).`